# Randomly generate non-zero positive integers such that sum is constant in R

Tags: r

I want to generate 'n' **random** **non-zero positive integers** such that the sum of all integers is constant.
For ex: I want to generate 5 non-zero positive integers (note that these are randomly distributed) whose sum is 7.

How can I do this in R ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
N <- 5
as.numeric(table(append(seq(1, N), sample.int(N, 7 - N, replace=TRUE))))
```

Comment: Neat, should be more generalized, though.

Comment: You could put that `7` into a variable; it's only used once, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here a rather brute force solution.

```
genInt <- function(n, z) {
  stopifnot(n <= z)
  repeat {
    s <- sample(1:ceiling(z/n), n, replace=TRUE)
    if (sum(s) == z)
      break
  }
  return(s)
}

set.seed(65222)
(r1 <- genInt(5, 7))
# [1] 1 2 1 1 2

(r2 <- genInt(10, 56))
# [1] 6 6 6 6 6 5 6 6 6 3

# Sum check
sapply(list(r1=r1, r2=r2), sum)
# r1 r2 
#  7 56
```

Comment: For higher `n`, this won't scale too well -- `genInt(n, n + 1)` is O(N^2), and `genInt(30, 31)` already takes too long to see it finish.

Comment: O(2^N), rather :-).

Comment: @Joe Sure. That's what I intended to express with "brute force" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
n <- 5
total <- 7
1 + rmultinom(1, total-n, rep(1,n))
```